# When debugging LibreOffice macro's, how do I get the error messages?

Tags: command-line, macros, libreoffice, basic

I am currently working on a LibreOffice macro that I want to run from the commandline in the background (i.e. without GUI). I call the macro like this:

> swriter  --invisible --nofirststartwizard --headless --norestore "macro:///Standard.Module1.myMacro(this is a string parameter)"

When I run this, the LibreOffice GUI for editing macro's comes up with a specific line selected. This line is as far as I can tell the first function call inside my macro function. My assumption is that this is the way LibreOffice wants to tell me an error occurred at this line and that the macro terminated.  At least, nothing is printed to the commandline.
My question is first: is this assumption correct? And if so: how do I check which error occurred? And: how can I check the internal state of the variables inside the macro?
Usually I would use print statements to debug languages without GUI debuggers. However print statements also give an 'error' as described above, so that is no option for me.